# Remove rows based on two conditions from data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to selectively remove rows from a data frame based on two conditions: the row names must match any value from a predefined character vector & the column names must also be a **partial** match to another predefined character vector. I am currently doing it as follows, but need a (much) faster work around that avoids using the loop. The original data frame is > 200k rows.

```
# generate a random data frame
set.seed(seed = 100)
df.data <- runif(80, 0,1)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(df.data, nrow = 10, ncol = 8, dimnames = list(rownames = seq(1,10), colnames = paste(c("A", "B"), rep(c("150","250"),4), sep = "_"))))

columns_to_filter <- c("150", "250")
rows_to_filter <- sort(round(runif(10, min = 1, max = 10), digits = 0))





# predefined character vectors containing strings for matching
columns_to_filter <- c("150", "250")
rows_to_filter <- sort(round(runif(10, min = 1, max = 10), digits = 0))


# the actual loop to match and replace matched values with NA
for(ii in 1:ncol(df)){
  for(jj in 1:nrow(df)){
    if(length(which(str_detect(colnames(df)[ii], columns_to_filter)) == TRUE) > 0){
      if(jj %in% rows_to_filter){
        df[jj,ii] <- NA
      }
    } else{
      df[jj,ii] <- df[jj,ii]
    }
  }
}

df <- na.omit(df) # removes rows containing NAs
dim(df)
```

Would appreciate any leads. Thanks.

Here are the dput() for original df:

```
structure(list(A_150 = c(0.338048706296831, 0.905447596916929, 
0.197556710103527, 0.794085179455578, 0.754602894652635, 0.911394847324118, 
0.322687704581767, 0.0861694731283933, 0.911200454225764, 0.95517382514663
), B_250 = c(0.671142943901941, 0.744982200907543, 0.440016976324841, 
0.115039417985827, 0.675642782123759, 0.731559516629204, 0.483984902733937, 
0.171048037940636, 0.675848534796387, 0.262989946408197), A_150 = c(0.34148082928732, 
0.210245542926714, 0.0163195941131562, 0.376762877451256, 0.562307401793078, 
0.679984607733786, 0.745388770475984, 0.950072722276673, 0.163090714253485, 
0.324756902176887), B_250 = c(0.132716035470366, 0.637297438690439, 
0.330929610645398, 0.649079572875053, 0.302888358943164, 0.0712332662660629, 
0.662390468874946, 0.75960356160067, 0.553360169287771, 0.539272097637877
), A_150 = c(0.849592320388183, 0.653225958812982, 0.950885756406933, 
0.617223048349842, 0.49284063372761, 0.976006565382704, 0.490345216123387, 
0.655172303086147, 0.598801789339632, 0.947569016367197), B_250 = c(0.368011507438496, 
0.878187005175278, 0.454875067807734, 0.496467015240341, 0.460615615127608, 
0.617908196756616, 0.604143491946161, 0.785879602655768, 0.555268474854529, 
0.768978339154273), A_150 = c(0.404285672586411, 0.510719809681177, 
0.523536442779005, 0.992799207800999, 0.429647421231493, 0.996011254843324, 
0.786600246559829, 0.515910634538159, 0.502687965519726, 0.911637484328821
), B_250 = c(0.264415897428989, 0.173856867710128, 0.400331255048513, 
0.538357384037226, 0.244964374694973, 0.37585095805116, 0.58025354729034, 
0.208955311682075, 0.801330007379875, 0.638802415458485)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

and the dput() for the processed df after the for loop

```
structure(list(A_150 = c(0.338048706296831, 0.905447596916929, 
0.794085179455578, 0.911200454225764), B_250 = c(0.671142943901941, 
0.744982200907543, 0.115039417985827, 0.675848534796387), A_150 = c(0.34148082928732, 
0.210245542926714, 0.376762877451256, 0.163090714253485), B_250 = c(0.132716035470366, 
0.637297438690439, 0.649079572875053, 0.553360169287771), A_150 = c(0.849592320388183, 
0.653225958812982, 0.617223048349842, 0.598801789339632), B_250 = c(0.368011507438496, 
0.878187005175278, 0.496467015240341, 0.555268474854529), A_150 = c(0.404285672586411, 
0.510719809681177, 0.992799207800999, 0.502687965519726), B_250 = c(0.264415897428989, 
0.173856867710128, 0.538357384037226, 0.801330007379875)), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "4", "9"), class = "data.frame", na.action = structure(c(`3` = 3L, 
`5` = 5L, `6` = 6L, `7` = 7L, `8` = 8L, `10` = 10L), class = "omit"))
```

Comment: By "column label", do you mean "column name"?  For example, `A_250` in your sample data?

Comment: Yes. Those are column and row names....

Comment: Clarified in the question now..

Comment: Your `dput()` for the original df is faulty: Error: Column names `A_150`, `B_250`, `A_150`, `B_250`, `A_150`, and 1 more must not be duplicated.

Comment: When I copy paste the dput() from the original df from above to my R console, it shows the expected data frame with 10 rows and 8 columns. Am I missing something? I just copy pasted the chunk from above into my console...I understand dplyr gives an error when there are duplicate column names, but my original data has that structure - i.e. it has many duplicated column names.

Answer (score 0):

A tidyverse solution would be:

```
library(tidyverse)

as_tibble(df, rownames="rowName") %>% 
  select(rowName, ends_with(columns_to_filter)) %>% 
  filter(rowName %in% rows_to_filter) %>% 
  select(-rowName)
# A tibble: 41 × 8
    C_150 D_150  A_150  B_150 A_250  B_250  C_250 D_250
    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1 0.244  0.133 0.111  0.372  0.559 0.441  0.679  0.764
 2 0.298  0.182 0.905  0.473  0.128 0.735  0.971  0.213
 3 0.180  0.153 0.121  0.0527 0.964 0.0758 0.862  0.780
 4 0.0104 0.924 0.486  0.924  0.368 0.0787 0.118  0.180
 5 0.493  0.934 0.302  0.433  0.152 0.581  0.713  0.376
 6 0.588  0.492 0.0265 0.271  0.367 0.496  0.857  0.298
 7 0.778  0.828 0.505  0.903  0.669 0.335  0.274  0.848
 8 0.472  0.375 0.161  0.844  0.544 0.492  0.0809 0.438
 9 0.862  0.592 0.598  0.975  0.654 0.900  0.400  0.477
10 0.319  0.274 0.857  0.492  0.353 0.314  0.406  0.489
# … with 31 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks. But this solution has also removed the entire columns, I just need the rows removed where values in specific rows && columns match...For instance - with my solution dim(df) = 61,20 (after na.omit) but with this tidyverse solution dim(df) = 40,8

Comment: I don't understand how you can remove a *row* based on a (partial) match of a *column* name.  Please add a call to `set.seed()` and the expected output based on your test input to your question.

Comment: The conditions are applied to data frame values (if i use the excel analogy - on cells). So for every value in the data frame, I need to remove rows only when the value's row name and column name both match values in the pre-defined vectors. I use set.seed - our solutions generate different results.

Comment: I believe it is unreasonable to expect anyone to provide a solution that matches yours when you refuse to provide your solution.  Your sample code does not include a call to `set.seed()`.  Voting to close for lack of clarity.

Comment: I have added the solutions as dput(). Please let me know if anything else can be added to make this more reproducible for others...